# How to extract only values greater than a threshold

Tags: awk, grep, logs

I am new to bash scripting. Could someone help me with the following?
I have a log file with output as shown below.

I'm trying to grep for lines of an output with logDurationMillis>=950ms

```
logAlias:Overall,logDurationMillis:382,logTimeStart:2019-07-24_15:30:06.075,logTimeStop:2019-07-24_15:30:06.107
logAlias:Overall,logDurationMillis:388,logTimeStart:2019-07-24_15:30:06.406,logTimeStop:2019-07-24_15:30:06.444
logAlias:Overall,logDurationMillis:545,logTimeStart:2019-07-24_15:30:06.583,logTimeStop:2019-07-24_15:30:06.638
logAlias:Overall,logDurationMillis:961,logTimeStart:2019-07-24_15:30:06.599,logTimeStop:2019-07-24_15:30:06.660
logAlias:Overall,logDurationMillis:640,logTimeStart:2019-07-24_15:30:07.197,logTimeStop:2019-07-24_15:30:07.237
logAlias:Overall,logDurationMillis:934,logTimeStart:2019-07-24_15:30:07.474,logTimeStop:2019-07-24_15:30:07.508
logAlias:Overall,logDurationMillis:336,logTimeStart:2019-07-24_15:30:07.546,logTimeStop:2019-07-24_15:30:07.582
```

The values are always in the second comma-delimited column.

Answer (score 11):

With awk:

1. if you know "logDurationMillis" is the second item:

   ```
   awk -F'[:,]' -v limit=950 '$4 >= limit' file
   ```
2. otherwise

   ```
   awk -F'[:,]' -v limit=950 '{
       for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) 
           if ($i == "logDurationMillis" && $(i+1) >= limit) 
               print
   }' file
   ```

Comment: I did not know you could do that with the delimiter!  Awesome

Comment: logDurationMillis is the second field so i tried the 2nd script you have provided, It worked.. Thank you so much

Comment: @Jesse_b: awk (even regular awk) can accept regexps as delimiter, and also extended ones (ex:  `-F 'this|that[ _]*also'` will separate fields with "this" and with "thatalso" or "that also" or "that_also" (and allow even multiple occurences of space or _, as there is a '*' in the regexp).  It can be really handy. Here,  in this answer, it separates fields with either 1 "," or 1 ":", so it will separate fields at each occurence of "," or ":" . (if the line starts with a separator, $1 is empty and $2 is the next field)

Comment: @glennjackman: Could you please edit that first one? to put $4 as you clearly intended to. (I am not sure if it is correct etiquette to edit it myself as it "changes" the answer...)

Comment: I did update it. It would be absolutely appropriate for you to edit my answer. The OP changed the input data after I answered, and a simple change like that does not alter the intent of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your file is named `logFile`, this command will do it:

```
egrep ',logDurationMillis:(9[5-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{3,}),' logFile
```

Comment: Using a regexp for a numeric comparison results in hard to understand/maintain code. To compare numbers, just use awk with a numeric comparison - there's zero reason to do this with regexps in grep.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk` one:

```
awk -F':|,' '$4 > 950' file
```

prints:

```
logAlias:Overall,logDurationMillis:961,logTimeStart:2019-07-24_15:30:06.599,logTimeStop:2019-07-24_15:30:06.660
```

---

**Update** (due to OPs Question:)

you can reconstruct the fields like this:

```
awk -F':|,' '$4 > 950 {print $3 ":" $4 "," $5 ":" $6 ":" $7 ":" $8 }' file
```

prints:

```
logDurationMillis:961,logTimeStart:2019-07-24_15:30:06.599
```

(there is probably a simpler way that concatinates the fields 3-8, but you also need to reconstruct the different field separators)

Comment: (1) This is basically the same as [glenn jackman’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/531947/80216#531953). (2) The question says “>=950”, but your answer says `> 950`.

Comment: That double pipe `||` looks odd. The intervening part would match the empty string too, but what use is that? Why not just `:|,`?

Comment: @ilkkachu:  Good catch; I missed that.  I suspect that nath meant `:|,` — as I said, equivalent to glenn’s `[:,]` — but reflexively typed `||` for “OR”.  But, AFAICT in six to eight minutes of testing, this answer works.  Can you demonstrate that the extra `|` actually causes it to fail?

Comment: @G-Man a `|` immediately following `|` is undefined behavior per POSIX, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03: `|
 ... A <vertical-line> appearing ... immediately following a <vertical-line> ... produces undefined results.`. So that code could do anything in any given awk.

Comment: Thanks Nath, 'awk -F':||,' '$4 > 950' file'  works :)

Actual log file is like 

logAlias:Overall,logDurationMillis:382,logTimeStart:2019-07-24_15:30:06.075,logTimeStop:2019-07-24_15:30:06.107, UniqueId....

question :How do i get only following fields in result

logDurationMillis:961,logTimeStart:2019-07-24_15:30:06.075,UniqueId

Comment: @ilkkachu, thanks for pointing this out, I changed the separator.

Comment: @G-Man I could not really see the use of assigning a variable here. So I thought making it easier. I could have suggested this to Glen though, I admit.

Comment: @Aslam534 I updated my post...